# Prevent breaking of specified part of paragraph

Tags: text-editing, iwork, iwork-pages, text-formatting

For example, we have a paragraph:

> Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

How can i prevent breaking the part "the lazy" ?
I means, that this string will be incorrect in my formatting:

> Quick brown fox jumps over the
>
> lazy dog

But this one is correct:

> Quick brown fox jumps over
>
> the lazy dog

My text is large and hitting "Shift+Enter" at some placed is ugly, because everything will crash, when text size will be changed ...

Selecting the part "the lazy", right-click -> "Prevent breaking" does not works

Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a non-breaking space between the words that you'd like to keep together.

I'm not familiar with Apple's iWork, but in **MS Office** and **OpenOffice** you can do this with <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Space</kbd>. It's sort of a standard shortcut, so you could try the equivalent combination for your system ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) says it's <kbd>Option+Space</kbd>).